# How to apply condtional validation in yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

I am using formik with Yup for validating fields. I want to validate two conditions(when both conditions fulfill than my validation should execute,for now, I am able to check with one condition  below is my validationschema .When users click on checkbox than he needs to enter from and to values which work fine but I want to also check one more condition that when spaceCycle value is === "Hourly" and checked is true than only this should execute.[can refer to this pic for better explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qknCl.png)

```
    const validationSchema = yup.object({
 
  spaceAvailability: yup.object({
    hours: yup.array().of(
      yup.object().shape({
        from: yup.string().when("checked", {
          is: true,
          then: yup.string().required("Please select hours"),
        }),
        to: yup.string().when("checked", {
          is: true,
          then: yup.string().required("Please select hours"),
          checked: yup.boolean(),
        }),
      })
    ),
    spaceCycle: yup.string().required("Please select atleast one option"),
  }),

 
});
```

Comment: Can you add your code [here](http://react.new/) . Its easy to try and test there.

Comment: @ShubhamVerma there is lot of dependency in my code so cannot upload whole code.

Comment: You dont have to upload whole code. Just create the poc for functionality required

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Facing some challenges uploading code but i want to do something like this yup.object().shape({
        from: yup.string().when("checked" && "spaceAvailability.spaceCycle", {
          is: true && "HOURLY",

          then: yup.string().required("Please select hours"),
        }),